# Combining Python code inside HTML with variables passed in

Tags: python, html, css, bottle

I am creating a web store with `HTML` and `Bottle` (`Python`). I know how to pass data between `HTML` and `Python`, as well as how to write `Python` code inside `HTML` (reference: http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html).

What I struggle with is writing `Python` code inside the reference that gets passed from `HTML` to `Python`.

I load images from a database since I have a lot of them. I set and pass the variables `image_name(index)` to `HTML` like this:

```
@get('/store')
def showStore():
    images = models.images() # reads from database
    data = ', number_of_images={}'.format(len(images))

    for (id, title, path) in images:
        data += ', image_name{}={}, '.format(id, path)
        data += 'image_title{}={}'.format(id, title)

    return template('store.html' + data)
```

The relevant part of `store.html`:

```
<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->

<div class="row">
    <% for i in range(1, number_of_images+1): %>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="static/images/{{image_name<%i%>}}.jpg">
          <h3> {{image_title<%i%>}} </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Since `Bottle` is not that well known: `{{image_title}}` in `HTML` gets the value passed in from the `template (html, variables)`. Block `<% %>` enables you to write `Python` code inside it.

Everything worked properly when I didn't use indexing of image properties inside the `HTML`, so `HTML` and the `for loop` do work, the problem is with this part:

```
{{image_title<%i%>}}
```

`<%i%>` should in my opinion create a variable `image_title`**i** but apparently it doesn't.

I get a `template not found` error, probably because the variables I am passing in (from the `.py` file) do not exist in the `HTML`.

The reason I would very much like to do this dynamically instead of hardcoding every image is that I have a lot of those images and every image has a whole table of relevant data I left out here because I would retrieve it in the same way as image's name and title.

I would appreciate any help with proper combining `Python` inside `HTML` with variables passed in since I really want to do it dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a rather large number of things wrong here.

Your template not found error is actually nothing to do with the strange manipulations you are doing within that template. It is because you are concatenating the template name with the `data` string in your call to `template()` in the last line of your Python code. I don't know bottle, but I'm absolutely positive the data needs to be a second parameter to that function:

```
return template('store.html', data)
```

As for the rest, there's absolutely no need to do anything that you are doing there. Just pass the images as a *list*, and iterate through that list in the templates. Dynamic variables are *always* a bad idea, and that applies just as much to templates as it does to standard Python code.

(Although note that you don't even create any dynamic variables; you just have a single string, formatted to look like a set of variable assignments. But that doesn't make it actually assign any variables anywhere.)

Comment: Didn't realize I can just pass in the list itself, thank you :)